# Horizontal centering of a div without knowing the div width, possible?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'm currently building a popup box script using css/jquery and i can't seem to get the div centered on the screen on all cases. It it possible to center it without knowing the div width?

Instead of posting all the code here i put up a live example at http://goo.gl/N45cp

Any kind of help is much appreciated!

Best Regards
John

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="child"></div>
</div>
```

If the position of the `#child` is not `absolute`, you can set left and right margins to `auto`:

```
#child {
   margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Or if the position is `absolute` you can try the following:

```
$("#child").css("left", function(){
    return ($("#wrapper").width() - $(this).width()) / 2;
});
```

Comment: That's probably the weirdest hack in CSS I've ever seen. Sadly, I'm just as guilty in using it, since it works.

Comment: @Raminson I tried to add a wrapper and add the jquery code to the script and this is what happend. http://goo.gl/N45cp or am I completely lost? :) thanks for helping out.

Comment: @Raminson http://jsfiddle.net/4yPxG/7/ but i could't get it to work on jsfiddle but the code is there but without jquery, thank you for looking into this.

Comment: @John you are welcome bro, try this, also instead of using `onclick` attribute you can use `click` or `hover` event handlers: http://jsfiddle.net/zvdRL/1/

Answer (score 4):

You can achieve this with pure CSS if you have a containing div:

HTML

```
​<div id="outer">
    <div id="inner">some content here</div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
​body, html, div#outer { height:100%; }
div#outer { text-align:center; }
div#inner { display:inline-block; }
```

http://jsfiddle.net/NjZbW/

​​​​​​​​​​​​​​

Comment: Doesn't seem to work with position: absolute; on the inner div?

Comment: This won't work until you get rid of that absolute positioning. Going with the container, and using it to middle the child is the way to go, but you need to lose the absolute positioning. If you want to go with absolute positioning (why? I would ask) then you will probably need a js helper on the css to position correctly.

Comment: I would advise you to stop specifying a full path since an id is just as unique. It only introduces unnecessary verbosity.

Comment: @LiamBailey Sorry but i need to use position: absolute for this task :( or is there another way?

Comment: @John, if you have to have position:absolute on the div then I believe you will have to know the dimensions of it, either by setting them in advance in the CSS or by getting them dynamically with JS.